# android bluetooth low energy heart rate monitor

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am making a bluetooth low energy heart rate monitor.
I have yoused this code but i have an eror in `if (btAdapter != null && !btAdapter.isEnabled())`
the error is unknow class: btAdapter

```
 BluetoothManager btManager = (BluetoothManager)getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);

BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = btManager.getAdapter();

if (btAdapter != null && !btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(enableIntent,REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the static getDefaultAdapter() method:

```
BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```